# Add to Shopping cart functionality(React+TypesScript+Tailwind css)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, shopping-cart

I am facing a problem in updating the cart badge number as I click the "add to cart" button.

[This is the Link to my entire code on Githhub.](https://github.com/amritpal7/react-vite-cart/blob/master/src/Components/ProductsList.tsx)

Comment: Please, post only the relevant code in your question. Take a look at the community guidelines

Comment: Please quote the piece of code you want help for ;) Now it's like: "I request assistance on this line of code, here is a pile of thousands of lines of code under which it is buried."

Answer (score 0):

in line number 18 absolute layer is not completely covered by relative causing `a` to swell so can't click the button, remove it or add class `relative` to the a tag on line 17 to fix the error